# how to assign a class in jquery from a php variable?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Is it possible to assign a class from a php variable to a new appended div in jquery?

```
$newItems = $('<div class="PHP VARIABLE PRINTS HERE A CLASS"></div>');
```

In my case, for other things, I am defining a var to defign what I then append in jquery but I need to get the class of the newly inserted div from a php variable. Is it possible?

Comment: Only if you are printing out this string with PHP, but if you have to do this then you're doing it wrong

Comment: That depends how you are processing the JavaScript file to start with. If it is passing through the PHP processor or it is static content

Comment: `<?php echo "class";?>` ? And @ExplosionPills, what's wrong with echoing php inside js?

Comment: @ExplosionPills, There are reasons why you might want to write JavaScript with PHP.

Comment: @DamienPirsy so in jQuery this is valid? $newItems = $('<div class="<?php echo "class";?>"></div>');

Comment: Try and see for yourself :). Your server won't explode anyway

Comment: that sounds like a yes!! Put that in an answer and I'll accept it :)

Comment: I agree that in general you would do best not mixing the two languages

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**In PHP**

```
<?php
    // First you need to have the variable with the name of classe
    $myClass = 'name_of_my_classe';
?>
```

**In Javascript:**

```
$newItems = $('<div class="<?php echo $myClass; ?>"></div>');
```

Comment: bingo! Thanks a lot. Didn't know I could simply put a php like that inside jQUery

Comment: If you're on newest PHP shortag should be enabled by default: `class="<?= $myClass; ?>"`

Comment: Remember that if you use shorttags you must set `short_open_tag = on` in PHP.ini

Answer (score 1):

There are two different ways I would imagine doing this.

Firstly you could use Ajax to get the variable earlier on, from the php variable, or you could simply echo the variable there inline from a function within the file.

The first way of doing this, using Ajax, is perhaps a more standard way of doing this, whereas I would count the latter method as a little bit quick and dirty.

Answer (score 0):

I think that hardcore mixing of PHP and JavaScript code is an anti-pattern and can lead to confusion.  I would limit PHP emissions to build HTML and use the JavaScript code to parse said HTML to get your desired client result:

```
//php
echo '<span hidden id=class-container data-class=name_of_my_class>';

//JavaScript
$("<div>").addClass($("#class-container").data('class'));
```

Comment: I am creating and appending the div with jQuery, not php tho

Comment: but it also prints it with php? i mean what happens to the echo? That'll print too no?

Comment: It prints the span with PHP.  The JavaScript can be in a separate file with the rest of your JS (recommended), or you can *also* print it out with PHP I suppose